# Вывести все числа, у которых четная сумма всех делителей

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
def sumchis(i):
    sum = 0
    d = [ x for x in range(1, i // 2 + 1) if i % x == 0 ]
    d.append(i)
    for j in d:
        sum += j
    return(sum)
def sop(a, b, sumchis):
    chet = []
    vsedel = []
    alch3 = []
    ind = []
    kon = []
    for i in range(a, b+1):
        alch3.append(i)
        ch = sumchis(i)
        vsedel.append(str(ch))
        if ch % 2 == 0:
            chet.append(str(ch))
    for q in vsedel:
        if q in chet:
            id = vsedel.index(q)
            ind.append(id)
    for ws in ind:
        seed = alch3[ws]
        kon.append(seed)
    return (kon)
print(sop(a, b, sumchis))
```

Не понимаю почему выводит такой результат

```
[3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 6, 12]
```

хотя должен `[3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12]`
В чем ошибка?
upd. Должно так быть, тк я сначала считаю сумму делителей каждого числа, затем беру только четные и надо вывести числа, соответствующие им. Числа должны выводиться всё время новые, а не повторяться

Comment: Потрудитесь задать вопрос более подробно. Почему результат должен быть именно такой?

Comment: Что в A и B? Как можно проверять вывод, если неизвестен ввод?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у вас чрезмерно усложнен код, делает кучу лишнего, зачастую с ошибками

ведь по сути алгоритм то состоит из нескольких шагов:

1. пройтись по всем числам из диапазона
2. для каждого числа пройтись по всем возможным делителям (т.е. от 2 до самого числа включительно)
3. если возможный делитель действительно является делителем (число делится на него без остатка), то сложить его с ранее найденными
4. если сумма делителей оказалась чётной - вывести ее на экран

Все.

Остальные действия излишни

```
a = int(input("Введите левую границу диапазона: "))
b = int(input("Введите левую границу диапазона: "))

for num in range(a, b + 1):
    # определить сумму делителей числа
    res = 0

    for divider in range(2, num + 1):
        if num % divider == 0:
            res += divider

    if res % 2 == 0:
        print(num, end=' ')
```

Вообще задачу в 1 строчку можно решить:

```
a = int(input("Введите левую границу диапазона: "))
b = int(input("Введите левую границу диапазона: "))

print(*[i for i in range(a, b + 1) if sum([j for j in range(2, i + 1) if i % j == 0]) % 2 == 0])
```

Вот у вас код находит сумму делителей:

```
def sumchis(i):
    sum = 0
    d = [ x for x in range(1, i // 2 + 1) if i % x == 0 ]
    d.append(i)
    for j in d:
        sum += j
    return(sum)
```

во-первых зачем вы считаете 1 делителем?

во-вторых зачем вы сначала формируете массив, чтобы по том по нему еще раз пройти?

в третьих зачем вы делаете цикл до середины числа i? понятно, что оптимизация скорости и вы в 2 раза скорость увеличите, но у вас не та задача, где это нужно

теперь код основной функции:

```
def sop(a, b, sumchis):
    chet = []
    vsedel = []
    alch3 = []
    ind = []
    kon = []
    for i in range(a, b+1):
        alch3.append(i)  # зачем
        ch = sumchis(i)
        vsedel.append(str(ch))
        if ch % 2 == 0:
            chet.append(str(ch))
    for q in vsedel:
        if q in chet:
            id = vsedel.index(q)
            ind.append(id)
    for ws in ind:
        seed = alch3[ws]
        kon.append(seed)
    return (kon)
```

зачем вы постоянно гоняете числа в строки? `print` и числа замечательно выведет

зачем перекладывать результат из одного массива во второй, а затем из второго в третий?

Comment: А вообще я же помню этот вопрос уже задавался на днях и я даже код писал тут в ответах. Опять что ли где-то задание на курсах дали студентам ))

Comment: @Zhilar спасибо, да задание дали

Comment: @Кирилл Ильиных, на будущее - пишите алгоритм сначала ловами на бумаги и лишь потом переносите в код - тогда будет все более -менее коротки, понятно и работоспособно, и не появится лишний функционал, который только ошибки вызывает

Comment: @Zhihar запомню, спасибо